# New state for each user in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

How can I achieve a new state for every user. And no user will encounter the other state value.
For example, a sample code:

```js
let countReq = 0;

exports.reqCount = (req, res) => {
    countReq++;
    res.status(200).send({req: countReq});
};
```

I want every user will get their own request count. Instead, in this scenario they are getting every user req count. Not only for this scenario, is there any way for every user req for a new state for the whole app?

Comment: Use sessions and cookies

Comment: thanks. any docs or blog or code?

Comment: can you please give a code for this question scenario how to handle with sessions and cookies?